# Find out the exact time to sleep in each thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jpanel

I am making a snake game. I have two threads (MAIN, Snake) and one thread for each frog(food) that i created. Frogs are able to move too but slower then the snake(so i would be able to catch them). Here is when things start to get interesting. In order to control snake and frogs movement i do this:

**Snake.java:**

```
public void run() {
        while (isAlive){
            move();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(delay);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}
```

I ask my thread to sleep for some time. I do the same with my MAIN thread so i dont have any problems with repainting my JPanel:

**GameController.java:**

```
void tick() {
        for (Frog frog : frogs) {
            if (CollisionChecker.checkFoodCollision(snake.getBody().get(0), frog)) {
                snake.grow();
                frog.respawn();
                score++;
            }
        }
        if (CollisionChecker.checkSnakeCollision(snake.getBody())){
            onStop();
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(snakeDelay);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

If i want to catch my frogs i have to make them sleep longer, so i did this:

**Frog.java**

```
public void run() {
        while (isAlive){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(snakeDelay * 3);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            move();
        }
}
```

Game works but when I sent my project for a code review I was told that this **3** from method **run()** is a magic number and I totally agree. I don't know what to do though. How do I manage my threads here?

**Edit:** seems like I had a false view on what is a "magic number".

Comment: Looks to me that you're just using the 3x factor to move frogs slower than snakes.  Declare it as "frogToSnakeRatio" or something equally descriptive and call it done.  Said another way, when it's clear what a magic number is, it ceases being a magic number.

Comment: As Andy implies, there's nothing wrong with using a constant. The problem is with using an unnamed constant that can look arbitrary to other people who are looking at your code. Making field names meaningful is one of the cornerstones of self-documenting code. Named constants also make modifying your code much more convenient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Frog` constructor might take a `long` argument which defines the `frogDelay`:

```
class Frog {
    private long delay;

    public Frog(long delay) {
        this.delay = delay;
    }

    public void run() {
        Thread.sleep(delay);
    }
}
```

When you are creating a `new Frog(calculateFrogDelay())`, the value of this parameter can be calculated by the constants `SHAKE_DELAY` and `RATIO`:

```
private final long SHAKE_DELAY = 100;
private final int RATIO = 3;

private long calculateFrogDelay() {
    return SHAKE_DELAY * RATIO;
}
```

You could add the ability to change these values at runtime - then you would need listeners to correct frog values.